# Drop WITH CHECK CONSTRAINT or a function in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have altered a existing table using the following query

```
ALTER TABLE CodeAccess
    WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT CK_CodeAccess_Code
    CHECK (dbo.chkCodeList('text1', 'text2', [Codes]) = 'True')
```

Now, I want to drop the function **chkCodeList(, ,)** from **CodeAccess** table. I have tried using

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'dbo.chkCodeList') 
    AND xtype IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF')
)
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.chkCodeList
GO
```

It gives following error

```
Cannot DROP FUNCTION 'dbo.chkCodeList' because it is being referenced by object 'CK_CodeAccess_Code'.
```

So, executing...

```
ALTER TABLE CodeAccess NOCHECK CONSTRAINT CK_CodeAccess_Code

Command(s) completed successfully.
```

Now, I am trying alter the table using the first query and it gives me...

```
There is already an object named 'CK_CodeAccess_Code' in the database.
```

and executing second query, I got same error message...

```
Cannot DROP FUNCTION 'dbo.chkCodeList' because it is being referenced by object 'CK_CodeAccess_Code'.
```

I also tried without prefix **dbo**

So, How can i remove the function **chkCodeList()**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dropping the constraint instead of `NOCHECK`. That is, `drop the constraint -> drop the function` like

```
ALTER TABLE CodeAccess  
DROP CONSTRAINT CK_CodeAccess_Code;

DROP FUNCTION dbo.chkCodeList;
```

In your case, you are setting `NOCHECK` but the constraint still exists and so, when you try running the `ALTER` command again it says object named 'CK_CodeAccess_Code' already exists.